# Calculate $\int_{0}^{20}\{x\}^{2}+\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor^{2}dx $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

I want to calculate the following integral
$$\int_{0}^{20}\{x\}^{2}+\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor^{2}dx $$

We have that $x=\{x\}+\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor$, then $x^2-2\{x\}\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor
=\{x\}^{2}+\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor^{2}$

$$\int_{0}^{20}\{x\}^{2}+\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor^{2}dx=\int_{0}^{20}x^2-2\{x\}\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor dx= \frac{20^{3}}{3}-2\int_{0}^{20}\{x\}\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor dx$$

How can I find the value of $\int_{0}^{20}\{x\}\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor dx$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The main idea here is that in each interval of length $1$, the fractional part of $x$ behaves exactly like $x$ (without the integer increase).  The greatest integer part over each interval is a constant and is equal to the lower bound of that interval.  Now integrating a constant from $5$ to $6$ is same as integrating it from $0$ to $1$.

$$\int_0^{20}(\{x\}^{2}+\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor^2) \, dx $$

$$=20\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx + \int_0^1 (0^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + 19^2) \, dx $$

Comment: Why does the second integral have a factor of $20$? $\qquad$

Comment: $$ \int_0^{20} \lfloor x \rfloor^2 \, dx = \sum_{n=0}^{19} \int_n^{n+1} \lfloor x \rfloor^2 \, dx = \sum_{n=0}^{19} n^2 \ne 20\int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^{19} n^2\,dx.$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy   You are absolutely right. I have edited and corrected my answer. Thank you so much for your time in correcting an older answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is easier to proceed in the following way:
\begin{align}
\int_0^{20}\{x\}^2+\lfloor x\rfloor^2dx & = \sum_{k=0}^{19}\int_k^{k+1}\{x\}^2+\lfloor x\rfloor^2dx\\
& = \sum_{k=0}^{19}k^2 + \int_0^1x^2dx\\
& = \frac{19\cdot20\cdot39}{6} +\frac{20}{3}\\
& = \frac{14840}{3}.
\end{align}
Of course, from this you can also deduce the value of $\int_0^{20}\{x\}\lfloor x\rfloor dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint, break it up into $\int_{n-1}^n$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots, 20$ and sum. The functions are much easier on these intervals.

Comment: Do you know of any general method for indefinite or improper integrals?

Comment: This is neither an indefinite nor an improper integral. @ThisIsNotAnId

Comment: I know; I was just curious if there existed any.